# Convert byte to enum by Marshalling IntPtr

Tags: c#

I'm trying to convert a byte array of size 1 to an enum:

```
public enum InformationMessageLevel : byte
{
    Information = 0,
    Warning = 1,
    Error = 2,
    Fatal = 3
}
```

Using marshalling:

```
   // bytes = byte[1] = 0
   // t is typeof(InformationMessageLevel)
unsafe
{
    fixed (byte* p = bytes)
    {
        var localPtr = p;

        return Marshal.PtrToStructure((IntPtr)localPtr, t);
    }
}
```

But I get the error:

> "The specified structure must be blittable or have layout
>   information.\r\nParameter name: structure"

The reason I'm using marshaling with an *IntPtr*, is this method is used to unserialize data dynamically to properties of different types.

Comment: What is the `t`?

Comment: `InformationMessageLevel result = (InformationMessageLevel) bytes[0];`?

Comment: Use `Marshal.ReadByte` instead. Also, do not use `Marshal` for serializing/deserializing data that will not leave the managed world. It's not designed for that, it's designed to marshal between managed and unmanaged. There are far better serialization solutions for managed-only code -- JSON, `BitConverter`, `BinaryFormatter`, `protobuf`... different technologies apply to different scenarios. `Marshal` is almost never the right choice.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko sorry should've been slower on the post button, updated question with reason.

Comment: What you want is InformationMessageLevel[] message = new InformationMessageLevel(size).  Then use  Marshal.PtrToStructure().

Answer (score 2):

A dynamic solution without using marshaling:

```
byte[] bytes = { 0 };
var t = typeof(InformationMessageLevel);
var result = Enum.ToObject(t, bytes[0]);

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Output:

```
Information
```